# Access Dagger subcomponent dependencies from parent android module

Tags: android, module, dagger-2, dagger

Recently I started to divide our application into smaller Android modules, but I'm having a hard time to make Dagger work the way I want it to.

My current dagger setup consist of:
- `ApplicationComponent` marked with `@Singleton`. This component is created on app start.
- `UserSubComponent` marked with `@UserScope`. This subcomponent is created when the user login.

Both these components is placed in my `app` module together with my `App` class who's responsible for creating both components.

In my `login` module (Which is a parent to my app module, so it can't access anything in the app module) I have my `AuthenticationManager`. 
When the user login I use RxJava to signal from my `AuthenticationManager` to `App`, so the `UserSubComponent` can be created.

My problem is that I need to access some dependencies from my `UserSubComponent`, after it have been created, in my `AuthenticationManager` so I can preload the user's data before moving on.

Module structure:

```
              app (AppComponent & UserSubComponent)
                                ^
                                |
  login (AuthenticationManager) - feature 2 - feature 3
```

My App class:

```
class App : DaggerApplication() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        authenticationManager
            .authenticationStateStream
            .subscribe { state ->
                if (state == AuthenticationState.AUTHENTICATED) {
                    AppInjector.userComponent.inject(this)
                }
    }
}
```

AuthenticationManager:

```
class AuthenticationManager @Inject constructor(loginApi: LoginApi) {

    @Inject
    lateinit var preLoader : PreLoader // This won't work because of different scope

    val authenticationStateStream = Observable<AuthenticationState>()

    fun login() {
        if (success) {
            authenticationStateStream.emit(AuthenticationState.AUTHENTICATED)
            // UserSubComponent is now created
            preLoader.preload()
        }
    }
}
```

App component

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class, AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    fun userComponentBuilder(): UserComponent.Builder
}
```

AppModule

```
@Module
class AppModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideLoginApi() = LoginApi()
}
```

UserSubComponent

```
@UserScope
@Subcomponent(modules = [UserModule::class, AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class])
interface UserComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun build(): UserComponent
    }

}
```

UserModule

```
@Module
class UserModule {
    @Provides
    @UserScope
    fun providesPreLoader() = PreLoader()
}
```

Can I somehow get this structure to work? Or what are my options when it comes to modules + dagger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a lot of trying, I finally managed to solve my problem.

What I discovered was:

- Don't use SubComponents when your app is divided into multiple modules.
- Each module needs it's own component (feature component)

I found this article really helpful:
https://proandroiddev.com/using-dagger-in-a-multi-module-project-1e6af8f06ffc

Answer (score 1):

When Dagger tries to create an object of `AuthenticationManager`, it will also try to inject any `@Inject` annotated fields as well. And that doesn't work as you correctly pointed out that `PreLoader` is from a different scope which essentially means that it is from a different component, i.e., `UserComponent`.

Important thing to note here is that `UserComponent` is not yet created at the point `AuthenticationManager` object is first created by Dagger. And since `PreLoader` is provided by`UserComponent`, there is no way Dagger could inject that field. However you can inject that field into `AuthenticationManager` by yourself.

Something like this:

```
class AuthenticationManager @Inject constructor(loginApi: LoginApi) {

    // Remove the @Inject annotation and provide a custom setter which will pre-load user data 
    private lateinit var preLoader : PreLoader
    set(preLoader) {
        field = preLoader
        preLoader.preload()
    }

    val authenticationStateStream = Observable<AuthenticationState>()

    fun login() {
        if (success) {
            authenticationStateStream.emit(AuthenticationState.AUTHENTICATED)
            // UserSubComponent is now created
            // You can't do this here:
            // preLoader.preload()
        }
    }
}
```

Your App class:

```
class App : DaggerApplication() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        authenticationManager
            .authenticationStateStream
            .subscribe { state ->
                if (state == AuthenticationState.AUTHENTICATED) {
                    // Here you can directly set the PreLoader object yourself
                    authenticationManager.preLoader = 
                                AppInjector.userComponent.preLoader()
                }
             }
    }
}
```

In order to access `PreLoader` object, you also need to modify your `UserComponent` like this:

```
@UserScope
@Subcomponent(modules = [UserModule::class, AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class])
interface UserComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    fun preLoader() : PreLoader // <-- Need to add this

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun build(): UserComponent
    }

}
```